# Creating a Pinterest-like layout for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've tried for too long to figure out how to convert [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2) into C# and iOS. I can basically find nothing that really helps me, especially on the .net side of things an was wondering if there is a kind soul that maybe has an example of an solution or is willing to maybe provide the code for such a solution.

Also, how would one use this solution with images that are being downloaded from a web request?

I've tried creating something similar which kinda works, problem is I can only simulate the different cell sizes, I can't figure out how to accually calculate the image size or how to even get the image information into my PrepareLayout() method in the Layout-class.

https://pastebin.com/jEXThW0X

```
public partial class CustomViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
{

    public CustomViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("ViewCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    public string ItemId { get; private set; }

    static CustomViewCell()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName("ViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);

    }

    public static CustomViewCell Create()
    {
        var cell = (CustomViewCell) Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];

        return cell;
    }

    public void Bind(ContentObjectViewModel model)
    {
        var imageUrl = $"myUrl/{image}";

        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ItemImageView.Image = ImageHelper.FromUrl(imageUrl);
            ItemId = model.Id.ToString();
        });


    }



    public async Task<UIImage> DownloadImageAsync(string imageUrl)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        Task<Byte[]> contentsTask = httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);

        var contents = await contentsTask;

        return UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray(contents));
    }
}


public class CustomDataSource : UICollectionViewSource
{
    public IEnumerable<ContentObjectViewModel> Items { get; set; }



    public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        var count = section == 0 ? 1 : Items?.Count() ?? 0;

        return count;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

            var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(CustomViewCell.Key, indexPath) as CustomViewCell ?? CustomViewCell.Create();

            cell.Bind(Items.ElementAt(indexPath.Row));

            return cell;

    }


}

public partial class CollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    private const int NumberOfColumns = 2;

    private readonly List<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes> _calculatedAttributes = new List<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>();
    private nfloat _contentWidth = 0f;
    private nfloat _contentHeight = 0f;

    private readonly nfloat[] _columnsXOffset = new nfloat[NumberOfColumns];
    private readonly nfloat[] _columnsYOffset = new nfloat[NumberOfColumns];

    public CollectionViewLayout(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void PrepareLayout()
    {
        base.PrepareLayout();
        _calculatedAttributes.Clear();

        _contentWidth = CollectionView.Frame.Width;
        var columnWidth = _contentWidth / NumberOfColumns;


        for (var i = 0; i < _columnsXOffset.Length; i++)
        {
            _columnsXOffset[i] = i * columnWidth;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < _columnsYOffset.Length; i++)
        {
            _columnsYOffset[i] = 0;
        }

        var attribute1 = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForCell(NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(0, 0));
        attribute1.Frame = new CGRect(_columnsXOffset[1], 0, columnWidth, 0);
        _calculatedAttributes.Add(attribute1);

        //_columnsYOffset[1] = _buttonHeight; // Second column has a vertical offset (due to sell button height)
        var random = new Random();
        var column = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < CollectionView.NumberOfItemsInSection(1); i++)
        {
            var cellHeight = random.Next(250, 500);
            var photoHeight = CollectionView.Frame.Height;
            var indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(i, 1);

            var frame = new CGRect(_columnsXOffset[column], _columnsYOffset[column], columnWidth, photoHeight);
            var insetFrame = frame.Inset(0f, 0f);

            var attribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForCell(indexPath);

            attribute.Frame = insetFrame;

            _calculatedAttributes.Add(attribute);

            _contentHeight = NMath.Max(_contentHeight, frame.GetMaxY());
            _columnsYOffset[column] = _columnsYOffset[column] + photoHeight;

            column = column >= (NumberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column;
        }
    }



    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
    {
        var attributes = new List<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>();

        foreach (var attr in _calculatedAttributes)
        {
            var intersection = CGRect.Intersect(attr.Frame, rect);

            if (intersection != CGRect.Empty)
            {
                attributes.Add(attr);
            }
        }

        return attributes.ToArray();
    }

    public override CGSize CollectionViewContentSize => new CGSize(_contentWidth, _contentHeight);


}

  public partial class TabProfileController : UIViewController
{
    private CustomDataSource _customDataSource;
    private readonly ContentServiceClient _contentServiceClient = new ContentServiceClient();
    private string _userId = "userid";
    bool useRefreshControl = false;
    UIRefreshControl RefreshControl;

    public TabProfileController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override async void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();


        AddRefreshControl();
        ProfileItemsCollectionView.Add(RefreshControl);

        imageViewProfilePicture.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("profilepic");
        imageViewProfilePicture.Layer.CornerRadius = imageViewProfilePicture.Frame.Size.Width / 2;
        imageViewProfilePicture.ClipsToBounds = true;


        //await LoadSaleItems();
        await InitializeCollectionView();


    }

    private async void HandleValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await RefreshAsync();
    }

    async Task RefreshAsync()
    {
        // only activate the refresh control if the feature is available  

            RefreshControl.BeginRefreshing();
        _customDataSource.Items = await _contentServiceClient.GetItemsForUser(_userId.ToString());
        ProfileItemsCollectionView.ReloadData();
            RefreshControl.EndRefreshing();


    }


    // This method will add the UIRefreshControl to the table view if  
    // it is available, ie, we are running on iOS 6+  
    void AddRefreshControl()
    {

        // the refresh control is available, let's add it  
        RefreshControl = new UIRefreshControl();
        RefreshControl.ValueChanged += async (sender, e) =>
        {

            await RefreshAsync();
        };
        useRefreshControl = true;

    }


    private async Task InitializeCollectionView()
    {
        var nib = UINib.FromName(CustomViewCell.Key, null);
        ProfileItemsCollectionView.RegisterNibForCell(nib, CustomViewCell.Key);

        _customDataSource = new CustomDataSource();


        var items = await _contentServiceClient.GetItemsForUser(_userId.ToString());
        _customDataSource.Items = items;
        ProfileItemsCollectionView.Source = _customDataSource;
        ProfileItemsCollectionView.ReloadData();

    }
```

Comment: I am a little reluctant to edit that Pastebin code in. What is the copyright of that code? As long as we don't know, we can't just copy it in.

Comment: Here is a new pastebin where I've added an MIT.https://pastebin.com/gjSBuu08

Comment: Check VariableSizedWrapGrid.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII That's for xamarin forms right? This is xamarin.ios.

Comment: @KasperP Apologies... There is a WrapLayout that is similar but I don't believe it will deliver the effect you're looking for.  Looks like a control simple enough control to make but is most likely going to have to be customized as you're doing now.

Comment: If you are deploying apps in iOS10+, why not try autoLayout to let system auto calculating the cell's size depending on its content's size just as tableview. Use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.AutomaticSize` to let your cell 
auto resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of research and some trial and error I've finally managed to understand delegates and how to use them in conjuction with Xamarin.iOS.

Basically what i had to do was to add the following to my Layout class:

```
public delegate CGSize CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewFlowLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath);
    public event CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout SizeForItem;
```

And then call the event ''SizeFoItem' in the loop that calculates the sizes of the cells.

Finally adding the call into my ViewController like so:

```
collectionViewLayout.SizeForItem += (collectionView, layout, indexPath) => {

            return new CGSize((View.Bounds.Width - 40) / 3, photoheight
        };
```

The variable photoHeight comes from a list of photos that gets initialized when the ViewController is constructed.